# Display possible corrections but do not apply them automatically

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, autocorrection

I have the following completion:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _approximate
```

As a result if I type something incorrectly and hit TAB I will see a list with corrected propositions (what I like) and at the same time misspelled word will be changed automatically at command line with first proposition (what I do not like). So how to get rid of this in-line automatic correction? I just want list of possible correction but command line should stick with original text.

Comment: Note that you can always _undo_ the correction with Ctrl-_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrections apply automatically because they are first on a group list, before `original`. You can change that with

```
zstyle ':completion:*' group-order original corrections
```

And the result is

[image]

Credit for the final solution goes to Stéphane Chazelas.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' original true
```

Then the original is added as a possible completion (last so you can press <kbd>Up</kbd>) and you get a description of what's happening.

For example, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `/usr/lco`:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>:

[image]

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl+_</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to undo the correction and cancel the completion.

Comment: I do know all of that, but my problem is not how to correct what was already corrected (undo), the real issue is with speed and efficiency. For example say I want to run `xemacs` so I write misspelled `xen` and hit <TAB>. I get whole bunch of possible corrections and my command line changes to `enable`. Now there are several steps which I have to do: 1. My brain need to realize what just happened (nonsensical corrections). 2. Correct back this correction (undo, C-c, whatever). 3. Write `xemacs` correctly. At the end of the day instead of gain half second I lost 5.

Comment: Just an idea: it is possible possible to rearrange completion group order like `zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*' group-order reserved-words parameters functions aliases builtins commands`. Isn't correction automatically applied because it is first on the group list, before `original`? If yes than maybe one can swap these groups...

Comment: @jimmij, yes, looks like `zstyle ':completion:*' group-order original corrections` works. Do you want to add your own answer?